# How to choose multiple files at same time in android

Tags: android, android-file

I have used this [library](https://github.com/ingyesid/simple-file-chooser) to choose file from a directory.

By using this library I can select one file. But I want to select multiple file and assign it to the file array.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(_context, FileChooserActivity.class);
((Activity) _context).startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER);
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    if ((requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
                        fileSelected = data.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_FILE_SELECTED);
 }
```

And in this code am getting Intent data and assigning to the String object fileSelected. How do i assign it to the File object?

Please give me an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mentioned lib doesnt support that

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Could you suggest me any other library?

Comment: @Murtaza Hussain yes. I tried that one. But there is nothing in the manifest file. It is showing an error.

Comment: copy standard manifest file from any project and change activity names

Answer (score 0):

As your mentioned lib doesnt support multiple file support.

Here is the alternative.
https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-Multiple-file-Selector-Dialog